# Setting Heap size and other JVM parameters in Grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails

I recently encountered the following error running a Grails application that will utilmately be a quartz job triggered by a cron (currently attached to a controller for development):

2014-11-21 12:37:34,538 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
Message: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I want to increase the Heap speace but I'm not sure of the correct way to do it for my grails version(2.2.4).

Do I create a GRAILS_OPT environment variable or do I use grails.project.fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you are needing to change these settings for development and doing so is accomplished using `GRAILS_OPT` environment variable. Consult instructions for your OS on how to do so.

From the Grails [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html):

> It's often useful to provide custom arguments to the JVM when running
>   Grails commands, in particular with run-app where you may for example
>   want to set a higher maximum heap size. The Grails command will use
>   any JVM options provided in the general JAVA_OPTS environment
>   variable, but you can also specify a Grails-specific environment
>   variable too:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
grails run-app
```